# Load avg is 65 and cpu is 100% on mysqld

Tags: mysql

Load avg is huge but all selects are treated immediate and updates are committed soon. 
I don't see any issues on indexing of tables or selects. But I suspect something has to be done for the below status. Any suggestion would be of great help. Today morning we migrated from 5.0 to 5.5.25 with row bin logs enabled. And now the perf sucks. Kindly suggest where to fine tune..

```
mysql> SHOW status LIKE 'qcache%'; 
+-------------------------+------------+ 
| Variable_name | Value | 
+-------------------------+------------+ 
| Qcache_free_blocks | 1 | 
| Qcache_free_memory | 1070253896 | 
| Qcache_hits | 42362 | 
| Qcache_inserts | 1275394 | 
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes | 0 | 
| Qcache_not_cached | 1433302 | 
| Qcache_queries_in_cache | 2805 | 
| Qcache_total_blocks | 5618 | 
+-------------------------+------------+ 
8 rows in set (0.10 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by logging your queries together with their execution times to try to find the worst offenders.

Also try to find out where load comes from so you can focus on the bottlenecks. A start can be to install `sysstat` and run `sar` regularly to collect information about memory usage, I/O and such.

Ask [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) for help with configuring MySQL optimally.